# A famous sentence

Tags: rebus

What is the famous sentence I am looking for?

[image: rebus]

Hints:

> The 'AM' doesn't have to mean a time... what else could AM stand for? Maybe a genius could figure it out.

> The exact letter positions in the bottom aren't too relevant, just that they are 'scrambled'. You can try to unscramble and clean them up. Eventually they will have to be scrambled though.

> That sheet should be colorful and filled with patterns, but we didn't have the budget.

A deeper hint:

> The groups of three lines represent jumping.

Comment: 2am could be the sudcorean group ?

Comment: Are the fonts important?

Comment: What I say are the fonts used for M and Y are the same but the Hs are different.

Comment: @IlCorsaroNero if you want to blindly guess at some random jargon that you probably came up with (no google results lol), then you can do so. But it's something more well known.

Comment: @1357924680a Intentional, but you don't need it to solve the rebus.

Comment: Are these meant for separation?

Comment: @1357924680a can you try to figure it out by yourself instead of asking the question author. Death of the Author, y'know?

Comment: Can I ask other hint?

Comment: is possible that the sheet is a crossword sheet?

Comment: @IlCorsaroNero If you have a partial answer, please just post it instead of guessing in the comments.